# JavaScript - find an object by ID in array and modify

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Please note that the following scenario is for the demonstration purposes only.

Lets assume I have a following array of object:

```
var obj = [{
    id: 4345345345,
    cat: [{
        id: 1,
        cat: "test1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        cat: "test2"
    }]
}, {
    id: 3453453421,
    cat: [{
        id: 1,
    }, {
        id: 2,
    }]
}];
```

My goal is to :

- Find an object within an array with `#id 4345345345`, add property `selected : true` to it
- Then within this object with `#id 4345345345`, find cat with `#id 2`, add property
  `selected : true` to it

---

The below works, however should my array have 1000+ objects it's feels somehow wasteful, can you please suggest any cleaner/clever solution ( possible using underscore)?

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var parent = obj[i];
    if (parent.id === 4345345345) {

        parent.selected = true;

        for (var j = 0; j < parent.cat.length; j++) {
            var sub = parent.cat[j];
            if(sub.id === 2) {
                sub.selected = true;
            }
        };



    }
};
```

Comment: If you've only got 1,000 elements, I wouldn't worry about it. **But** if you really want to be anal about performance.... 1) Can you guarantee that only 1 element will be matched? If so, break out the loop once you've matched an element. 2) You could sort your array in order of ID, then use binary search rather than linear.

Comment: Seems better suited for codereview.SE

Comment: It feels wasteful because you're doing a brute-force search of a large array to see if the `id` matches a specific value. If you knew the array were going to be in order (e.g. the object with `id` 122 were always the nth member of the array) you could just do `obj[n]` to get it instead of using the loop.

Comment: Try to insert them in sort order (id), you should then be able to find items very fast even if there are millions, using binary search or such. This is of course worth it mostly if you seek more than insert.

Comment: @Matt - ID's will be unique

Comment: @Iladarsda; then, like I said *break out the loop once you've matched an element*.

Comment: @kmoe - array would be sorted but some ID's will be missing (deleted), so `obj[arrayPosition]` would not work in this case

Comment: Okay so if the array is always sorted, I guess you have two options: (1) use @Matt's and @npup's idea of a binary search, or (2) rewrite the bit of code that deletes the IDs from the array so you just have a `deleted: true` property or something. Depending on your code, (1) will probably be a lot easier. :)

Comment: @npup - binary search with JavaScript? ;) this sound like magic.

Comment: I'd use a couple of objects to store the different data types, and then write a couple of methods to access them, similar to what @kmoe suggested. [Here's a prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/eanndfjg/)

Comment: @Iladarsda Why? Check out what it means :) It is just an algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches I can think of

1) change your data structure to use the id's as the key. ie.

4345345345 :
    cat: { 1 :{
        cat: "test1"
    }, 2 : {
        cat: "test2"
    }}

2) Alternatively you can create a temporary lookup table based on the id to directly look the object actual objects; obviously you would only create the look up table one time, or whenever the data changes. This will bring your runtime from O(n) to O(1).

Comment: How to do #1 ? I need this as well!